# Customize "Update google play services" dialog

Tags: android

Im trying to customise the Dialog where it displays errors based on a status code coming from the method

> googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);

This method returns a status code that then gets passed into a method

> googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, status, 2404).show();

Which then shows a dialog to the user asking them whether they need to update Google Play Services or enable them etc based on the error code ("status" in this case). From what i can tell is they set the dialog text based on the status, but I want to customise it a bit because I am using it for notifications so I want to say in the dialog that the user wont be able to use notifications without this feature installed/enabled/updated on the app?

Also I want to be able to add a Cancel button with custom text like "It's Ok" or something along those lines?

I've seen something similar in another app and thought it was a great idea.

EDIT:

```
   public static boolean checkGooglePlayServices(Activity activity) {
    GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int status = googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activity);
    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
      if (googleApiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(status)) {
        Dialog dialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(activity, status, 1);
        dialog.setTitle("This is a test title");
        dialog.show();
      }
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
```

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to build your own dialog. or, if you're into a very hacky solution, getErrorDialog() is returning a dialog, you could manipulate it's View before showing it...

Comment: @lelloman i have already tried this and it seems i cannot alter the text in the dialog, only the title which is really weird

Comment: maybe you want to add the code you tried to the question, if altering the text of the dialog would be a good solution for you maybe we can make it work. anyway, it's dirty, just make your own dialog it takes very little effort

Comment: @lelloman please refer to the comment i added to the answer that was suggested by NitZRobotKoder

Comment: @lelloman BTW i added the code i am working with, as you can see i tested with dialog.setTitle("This is a test title"); (thinking .setTitle wasnt going to set the title haha) and of course it did set the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**resultCode can have below values.**

```
public static final int SUCCESS = 0;
public static final int SERVICE_MISSING = 1;
public static final int SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED = 2;
public static final int SERVICE_DISABLED = 3;
public static final int SIGN_IN_REQUIRED = 4;
public static final int INVALID_ACCOUNT = 5;
public static final int RESOLUTION_REQUIRED = 6;
public static final int NETWORK_ERROR = 7;
public static final int INTERNAL_ERROR = 8;
public static final int SERVICE_INVALID = 9;
public static final int DEVELOPER_ERROR = 10;
public static final int LICENSE_CHECK_FAILED = 11;
public static final int CANCELED = 13;
public static final int TIMEOUT = 14;
public static final int INTERRUPTED = 15;
public static final int API_UNAVAILABLE = 16;
public static final int SIGN_IN_FAILED = 17;
public static final int SERVICE_UPDATING = 18;
public static final int SERVICE_MISSING_PERMISSION = 19;
public static final int RESTRICTED_PROFILE = 20;
```

**do not call getErrorDialog instead call your owndialog and take action accordingly..**

```
 static String getStatusString(int var0) {
        switch(var0) {
        case -1:
            return "UNKNOWN";
        case 0:
            return "SUCCESS";
        case 1:
            return "SERVICE_MISSING";
        case 2:
            return "SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED";
        case 3:
            return "SERVICE_DISABLED";
        case 4:
            return "SIGN_IN_REQUIRED";
        case 5:
            return "INVALID_ACCOUNT";
        case 6:
            return "RESOLUTION_REQUIRED";
        case 7:
            return "NETWORK_ERROR";
        case 8:
            return "INTERNAL_ERROR";
        case 9:
            return "SERVICE_INVALID";
        case 10:
            return "DEVELOPER_ERROR";
        case 11:
            return "LICENSE_CHECK_FAILED";
        case 13:
            return "CANCELED";
        case 14:
            return "TIMEOUT";
        case 15:
            return "INTERRUPTED";
        case 16:
            return "API_UNAVAILABLE";
        case 17:
            return "SIGN_IN_FAILED";
        case 18:
            return "SERVICE_UPDATING";
        case 19:
            return "SERVICE_MISSING_PERMISSION";
        case 20:
            return "RESTRICTED_PROFILE";
        case 21:
            return "API_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED";
        case 42:
            return "UPDATE_ANDROID_WEAR";
        case 99:
            return "UNFINISHED";
        case 1500:
            return "DRIVE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_REQUIRED";
        default:
            return (new StringBuilder(31)).append("UNKNOWN_ERROR_CODE(").append(var0).append(")").toString();
        }
    }
```

PS: **See ConnectionResult.java class for more info.**

Comment: I've thought about this as well my issue that i haven't really looked into is was to handle each scenario (that can be fixed by the user) like enabling the services, updating (taking them straight to the google play store) or the service is missing in general

Answer (score 0):

**Warning: The following "solution" should be handled with care, as it does not use public api (as far as i know) and the string names might change in the future.**

**Implementing a custom dialog (as suggested by lelloman) might be the better solution.**

I found the following strings in the play-serrvices-base resource folder res/values/values.xml which are used in the error dialog (depending on the error code):

- common_google_play_services_enable_button
- common_google_play_services_enable_text
- common_google_play_services_enable_title
- common_google_play_services_install_button
- common_google_play_services_install_text
- common_google_play_services_install_title
- common_google_play_services_notification_channel_name
- common_google_play_services_notification_ticker
- common_google_play_services_unsupported_text
- common_google_play_services_update_button
- common_google_play_services_update_text
- common_google_play_services_update_title
- common_google_play_services_updating_text
- common_google_play_services_wear_update_text

You can override them in your strings.xml file.

Comment: See ConnectionErrorMessages.java class for more info